# Tasks which require professional licenses by non-licensed persons

Tags: united-states, licensing, california

**Background** (as I understand it in California)

My friends, some stranger, or myself are allowed to do minor repairs (minor plumbing or electrical work) to a home, without the need for professional licenses/certifications. As long as no one is doing it as a paid professional.

We can also do major renovations or demolitions (major plumbing, etc.) as long as we get local permits first.

Again, all without the need for professional licenses/certifications. As long as no one is doing it as a paid professional.

**Question**

If I'm filming and paying actors doing these tasks, would this be legal?

I've hired them to **act** like licensed professionals not **be** licensed professionals.

In these situations/scenes, these tasks may or may not get complete fully, but they would be doing the **actual tasks**, not just a fake version of them.

Comment: What is the context of the films? Fiction films? Or how-to films? If how-to, you may need to run a disclaimer as to the accuracy of the portrayed work. (Think This Old House disclaimer).

Comment: The context would be fiction/fantasy. I'm not worried about liability from viewers. But the legality for the producers and actors by making the production.

Comment: You're wrong about asbestos abatement. See section 1.3 of [this pdf](http://www.aqmd.gov/docs/default-source/compliance/Asbestos-Demolition-/1403-frequently-asked-questions.pdf). Legal owner who is resident in house can do it, but cannot be helped by anyone.